Unable to Deploy Instances on OpenStack as Volumes are failing to Create in Ceph Backend
I have recently installed Canonical OpenStack (Sunbeam) from snap channel 2024.1/beta on both single and multi node setup.. although all services seem to be showing up and running.. I am not able to create volumes as it says: "schedule allocate volume:Could not find any available weighted backend".. I tried different hardware / setup but it's the same issue.. We would like to use this in production for us and our clients and may eventually take Ubuntu Pro support but would really appreciate if there can be any indication on how to resolve the issue I am having. By the same approach and installation was working on the same hardware when I tested it around early November this year and now it doesnt. There has not been any change to my hardware or setup since.
Would really like some help to ensure that this is something that is a known issue and has a fix as this will help us to determine whether canonoical openstack product will be suitable for us for production and client deployments.
